# Firebase real-time database error in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This error happens when I click the category from which I expect to see all the categories from firebase where I put all the category names and pictures. I am a beginner of Android studio and not many solved issues can be found in the search on Google.

```
04-07 18:35:13.271 25281-25281/com.example.a2015015407.edenparkproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.a2015015407.edenparkproject, PID: 25281
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database url specified
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepd.zzqj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.example.a2015015407.edenparkproject.CategoryFragment.onCreate(CategoryFragment.java:41)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2328)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1379)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1188)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1071)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:115)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2379)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Invalid scheme specified: Category
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepd.zzqj(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
at com.example.a2015015407.edenparkproject.CategoryFragment.onCreate(CategoryFragment.java:41) 
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2328) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1379) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1188) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1071) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:115) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2379) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: My best guess based on the error message is below. But please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable, example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because it's hard to help without seeing one of those - and you're much more likely that someone can help *with* an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you're initializing Firebase with an invalid URL:

> Invalid Firebase Database url specified

My guess is that you're calling [`getReferenceFromUrl("some/path")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)). To get a reference, instead call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("some/path")` as shown in the [getting started page of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Update: it looks like you need:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category")
```

Comment: private void loadCategories() {
        adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder>(
                Category.class,
                R.layout.category_layout,
                CategoryViewHolder.class,
                categories

           @Override
    public void onCreate(  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("Category");


    }

Related code is above.

Comment: Yeah, that makes no sense: you're calling some of the more advanced APIs there, which you're *very* unlikely to need at this point. Please follow the documentation I linked, or the code I showed: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category")`